How can solve "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'" problem
this my index.tsx file:
import React from "react";
import UserInput from "./userInput";

import {
  View,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';


const App = ( ) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar hidden/>
      <UserInput/>
    </View>
  );
};


export default App;


and this my userInput file:

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const UserInput = ( text: string ) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        { text }
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default UserInput;

my problem on index.tsx file on  tag
this tag i made it has 1 param. I cant give a value to it.
I google it but i cant find any answer.

UserInput is expecting a text prop but you're not passing one in <UseInput text="Test" /> and, because a component's props is an object you also need to destructure that text prop from it: ({ text }) => 

can any one show this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79133414/invariant-violationnew-nativeeventemitter-requires-a-non-null-argument-js-e

Every function for a React component has one parameter, referred to as props.
This parameter is an object containing all the props passed to the component like you wanted to do with text.
Because it is an object, you would have to either use the dot method (props.text) or, more commonly done, destructure the object like Andy has already commented:
const UserInput = ({text}: {text: string}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        { text }
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

